# c++ template class type instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

Why compiler can't find match and instantiate automatically?

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct A
{
  A( const T1& t1_, const T2& t2_ )
  : t1( t1_ ), t2( t2_ )
  {}

  T1 t1;
  T2 t2;
};

int main()
{
   double d = 5.2;
   std::string s( "hi" );
   A a( d, s );  // this doesn't compile (gcc)
   A<double, std::string> a1(d, s);  // OK
}
```

Compile error from gcc:
error: missing template arguments before 'a'
error: expected ';' before 'a'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template parameter deduction only happens for calls to function templates.  If something like your example were allowed, it would at best be very confusing when you add complications like multiple class constructors, constructors that use the template arguments in a different order, in different ways, or not at all.

In cases like this, we'll often use a "make" function to complement the class template:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
A<T1, T2> make_A( const T1& t1, const T2& t2 )
{ return A<T1, T2>( t1, t2 ); }

int main()
{
    double d = 5.2;
    std::string s( "hi" );
    auto a = make_A( d, s );
}
```

Comment: thanks.  but I don't see why it would be confusing in case of multiple class constructors.  In my example, if A derives from class B and C, say, it still doesn't matter -- the only thing the compile should look at is type of variable d and s, which are explicitly defined.  I would understand if A a( 5.2, "hi" ) doesn't work.  But d and s's types have been explicitly defined already.

Comment: Multiple constructors in the same class, not multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

It didn't work because you didn't specify the parameterized types.  You might think you did, but all you specified were constructor arguments, not template arguments.  There could conceivably be a template specialized constructor of `struct A` with the same constructor arguments but different template arguments.

Sure, the compiler could have tried to deduce the type from the arguments and compile without warning if it finds a unique match, but wouldn't that be a ticking time bomb waiting to blow up the instant you make this constructor: `A< int, string >::A ( double, string )`?

In fact, I think the other reply suggesting a `make_A()` function is asking for trouble too.  Somewhere buried your code you might have a `make_A(5,"whatever")`, blowing up somewhere far downstream.  If you don't like to type it out, why not use a `typedef` or `using`?  I've always found `auto` to require vastly more effort to read.

Comment: Yes, it does depend on the situation.  And you do need to be careful with things like `std::make_tuple`, `std::make_shared`, `std::make_unique`, etc, but they're still useful functions.

Comment: @KevinZ - agreed that A< int, string >::A ( double, string ) -- is a time bomb.  In that case, the compile should come up with a compile warning that assigning double to int might be trouble.  Just like when u pass in double into a function taking int.  All I'm saying is, that didn't seem like to be a stumping stone for it not to do auto type deduction, to me at least.  If it can do it for functions,  templated functions, why not constructor?

Comment: @surfcode: Nobody said `A<int, string>::A(double, string)` would assign a `double` value to an `int` variable.  There could be a computation in between, no member of type `int` at all, or lots of other possibilities.  None of this would be able to make a difference for type deduction.

Answer (score -1):

It seems as though any object of type A should have two arguments, i.e. double and std::string.

The line of code that does not compile does not utilize these arguments.